# Reflection: Retrieve name or field that return value is assigned to

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, stack-trace

Is it possible to retrieve the field name, where the returned object is *assigned to* using the `StackTrace` object and reflection?

---

In this example, the `CreateFooObject` method needs to know the name of the field to which the returned object is assigned to ("Foo"). The previous stack frame is obviously `.cctor`, however is there a way to get the actual field in question?

```
public static readonly object Foo = CreateFooObject();

public static object CreateFooObject()
{
    StackFrame[] stack = new StackTrace().GetFrames();

    // get name of field: "Foo"
    string fieldName = ...;

    return ...;
}
```

**Background:** I'm wrapping up the `DependencyProperty.Register` method to make it parameterless. I've already taken care of the two `Type` parameters which I can retrieve through reflection. What's left is the `name`. So in essence it's WPF syntactic sugar for boilerplate code.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to do? What if the return value is not assigned to anything, or what if the method call is part of another expression? What do you want to happen in those cases?

Comment: I'm wrapping up the `DependencyProperty.Register` method. I've already taken care of the two `Type` parameters which I can retrieve through reflection. What's left is the `name`. So in essence it's WPF syntactic sugar for boilerplate code.